# Wrong value on cpu usage from Node Exporter

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-node-exporter

I would like to setup monitoring with prometheus, node exporter and grafana. I'm using Node Exporter to monitor cpu/memory on server.
I used the expression as below on Grafana.

`100 - (avg by (instance) (rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{job="node",mode="idle"}[1m])) * 100)`

However, this cpu value always has low value than expectation.
Even cpu have been reached 95-98% by measure from "top" command in linux. The value show only 40-50%.
Could you please give me any suggestions? How to fix this wrong value? or wrong expresstion?

[image]

Comment: 98.7% of CPU usage from the `top` screenshot means that 98.7% of a _single core_ is used. It's clear that there are more than one core on that machine and since you're using `avg by(instance)` it shows you average (mean) load among all cores on the node. Thus, if half of the machine cores is under 100% load, and the other at 0%, then 50% is the average.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "%CPU" shown by the "top" command is the percentage of your CPU that is being used by the process. By default, top displays this as a percentage of a single CPU. On multi-core systems, you can have percentages that are greater than 100%. For example, if 3 cores are at 60% use, "top" will show a CPU use of 180%. See here for more information. You can toggle this behavior by hitting Shift+i while "top" is running to show the overall percentage of available CPUs in use.

See more information [here](https://scoutapm.com/blog/understanding-linuxs-cpu-stats).

Comment: that's mean the value should be correct. Is it possible to find average cpu usage from top command? or something else that I should use for reference that show the average cpu usage in linux.

Comment: A fixed the answer (the "i" was missing in the "shift+i" toggle). You can try to use "htop" command instead of "top". It has the CPU average option.